# SQL query through java returning "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, mysql, database

```
try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/phpMyAdmin/Database_Name","root","");  
     stmt=con.createStatement(); 
    }
```

This is my code to establish a connection b/w my computer and database and after this I receive the user name and password from the user and then i execute this query

```
try {
      rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM d
      teacher_info WHERE UserName 
       = '"+userName+"' AND teacher_info.password 
        ="+password);
    }
```

The problem is that whenever i execute the query i get 
java.lang.NullPointerException 3 times in a row
Any ideas as to why this could be happening ?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Read [ask] and improve your question. Add a [mcve]

Comment: that is not how you write queries in 2017, open to SQL injection, http://bobby-tables.com/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: And when you don't know how to deal with such exceptions than data base work is beyond your current skills. You are simply overburdening yourself.

Comment: @GhostCat I would agree but I wish I could tell that to my academic institution :D

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues with your query and code

1. missing space here `= '"+userName+"' AND teacher_info`
2. you can't access another table column `teacher_info.password` just like that  without some kind of `JOIN` (`join` with the said table)
3. don't concatenate user input like that rather use parameterized query to avoid *SQL Injection* attack
4. Also missing single quotes `'` on this one `.password ="+password);`

Comment: Also missing two `'` on this one `.password ="+password);`

Comment: 1. where exactly is the space missing? 2. @Luke only if the password is a string. if its digits only, then its oaky

Comment: @Luke, nice catch ... included in answer. Thanks

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, look carefully and you will see space missing before `AND` ... also even if it's digits .. password always is alphanumeric which is `varchar` in SQL. have you ever seen `password int`?

Comment: @Rahul a pure password int would be for example the phone pin. copied from your answer `' AND t` and there is a space between `'` and `AND`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Your phone-pin could never start with a zero then.

Comment: @Luke thats not really the point. the point is that he can have some custom password stuff which can be stored as integer

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, point is password would never be stored as integer cause then it would allow for manipulation of the int

Comment: The space is present and I thought you don't need '' for integers what am I concatenating ? I am getting a string and int input .....I also fixed the table name confusion, I don't need to join as its the same table.